# How to print array objects in a messageDialog and add a new line every 5 objects #java

Tags: java

how to print array objects in messageDialog and add new line every 5 objects.
instead of getting a list of numbers in one line: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 instead i need them to be printed in new line every 5 objects

`````
      String inMessage ="";
      String message=randomNum[0]+" "+inMessage;
      for(int i = 1; i<randomNum.length; i++){
          message += randomNum[i]+" ";
          counter++;
          if(counter % 5 == 0){
          inMessage += randomNum[i] +"\n";
          }
      }
      showMessageDialog(null, message);
  }````
`````

Comment: `showMessageDialog(` this is using JOptionPane?

Comment: yes. i imported javax.swing.JOptionPane.*;  at the begining of my whole code

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the showMessageDialog call refers to the JOptionPane method with this name, the easiest way to get this done is to use a non-editable JTextArea

`````
  String inMessage ="";
  String message=randomNum[0]+" "+inMessage;
  for(int i = 1; i<randomNum.length; i++){
      message += randomNum[i]+" ";
      counter++;
      if(counter % 5 == 0){
      inMessage += randomNum[i] +"\n";
      }
  }
  JTextArea area = new JTextArea();
  area.setText(inMessage);
  area.setEditable(false);
  showMessageDialog(null, area);
}````
`````

There are other ways to do this, but this is probably the easiest

Comment: this is for my school assignment so i need to do it in the most primitive way possible. I guess that would be one of those hardar ways that I cannot come up with